How to change variable inside Inspector app.config w/ Sanic
I want to change the variable in the config. which is in app.config.var. It is possible to by using the Inspector change the config. variable data? I just want to use sanic commands to do so.
class MyInspector(Inspector):
    
    async def change_variable(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
        # app.config.data = kwargs.get("data")


How can I access the app.config? Is it even possible? I was unable to find anything related to this on the internet? should I create routes instead?
